# Will android system recycle bitmap automatically even have references to the bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco, recycle

I implemented a custom widget that has a `SparseArray` which have a array of
bitmaps, when I scroll other UI widget frequently(scroll ListView quickly) make memory allocation frequently and become large, at this time I counter a 
problem that I can reference Bitmap from SpareArray and Bitmap is not null, but the Bitmap's status become recycled and I never do bitmap.recycle() operation!
So the problem is will android system recycled bitmap automatically when memory is not enough even you have reference to it?

Comment: found the reason: fresco did

Comment: You are saying that the fresco library was calling `bitmap.recycle()` and that caused your problem?

Comment: @Jon yes. I didn't copy bitmap from fresco, fresco will auto recycle bitmap even you have a reference to it.so the safe way is to copy it when get bitmap through fresco.

Comment: Then I recommend you write that as a separate *answer*. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer